# Why is Saraswati shown with Ganesha and Lakshmi?

Tags: ganesha, lakshmi, saraswati

Picture frames, especially the one in Diwali, Lord Ganesha is shown with Goddess Saraswati and Goddess Lakshmi.

Why is that so? I know the story of Lakshmi adopting Ganesha as his son from Parvati.

So that make sense for Lakshmi portrayed with Ganesh but why Goddess Saraswati is also portrayed with them?

Comment: Because Saraswati = Goddess of Knowledge, Lakshmi = Goddess of Wealth, and as we say, lord Ganesh = Wealth + Knowledge

Comment: Diwali is actually three days festival (or five), Each day stories are related to these Gods.

Comment: @Mr_Green Lakshmi Pujan, Chopda Pujan and lord Ganesh is whom we always worship before starting any puja

Answer (score 6):

I belong to [Smarta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smarta_tradition) family.

Till photography became popular in India in Mid 19th century and selling of photos/colour paintings of Gods had become a commercial business, idols of Gods were used to be worshipped.

Way back in late 1980s, when I was still in early twenties, I had observed in houses of our relatives and family friends, people of old generation,ie., of 1900 - 1950s, used to keep picture of female TRINITY, i. e., Saraswati, Lakshmi and Parvati in a single picture, in their houses.

[image]

This devotion to female TRINITY is prevalent in the families,  who are regular reciters of [Devi Mahatmya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devi_Mahatmya) or Durga Saptasathi.  In Durga Saptasathi, which is a part of Devi Bhagavatam, Devi has been eulogised as the eliminator of Mahishasura, Chanda, Munda, Nishumha, Raktabhija, Shumba, etc.  Lakshmi, Saraswati, and Durga will be eulogised while reciting certain chapters.

I don't want to quote [folklore like this](https://www.templepurohit.com/lakshmi-ganesha-worshipped-together/) of adoring Lakshmi and Ganapati together.

Certain people, especially from business community, might have popularised the image of  Lakshmi, Ganapati and Saraswati, removing Parvati, as they are more interested in getting obstacles removed while doing business. As Ganapati is the son of Parvati, the latter might have been removed.

In some families, Ganapati will be worshipped even before doing Saraswati puja for children.

Comment: Ah makes sense! I have observed this only in North part of India, is it been practised in south part of India as well ?

Comment: Yes,  please.   Now a days,  Sri Shirdi Sai joined the group of Lakshmi, Saraswati and Ganesha in some photos :-) @TheLittleNaruto

Answer (score 1):

Hindu rituals make it mandatory for Ganesha to be worshiped before the start of any Pooja.
Hence, Ganesha is a part of the frame. Also, Ganesha is generally considered as the Lord of wealth and the bestower of knowledge.

In Diwali we celebrate and workship wealth. But true wealth comes only when a person has knowledge or talent . Its said Lakshmi finds the home of the learned only. Since Saraswati is the goddess of books and music (talent), even she is worshiped with Ganesha.

You'll like to read about Devdutt Pattanaik's blogs. He explains all these questions very well.

Here is the link to his website: http://devdutt.com/

Comment: @user3426358 - Do you have any references in standard hindu scriptures like Vedas, ithihasa (Ramayana/Mahabharata) principle 18 puranas or standard upanishads or standard smritis where it is mention Lakshmi and Ganesh should be worshipped together? As far as i know there is no validity to it...Lakshmi should always be worshipped with Vishnu or his avataras only...For that matter no other goddess, whether it is Lakshmi or Parvati or Saraswati should be worshipped alone...They should be always be worshipped with their respective consorts only.

Comment: @Krishna Well, Saraswati is an unusual case, since worship of Brahma is prohibited.

Comment: @Keshav - I am not sure, i don't think worship of brahma is totally prohibited, though there are puranic instances saying so...His worship through temples is prohibited, i suppose...That was due to the curse of Bhrgu..Sorry in case i am wrong...That is why you see in bramhotsavam on tirumala lord brahma goes about in a chariot before the start of utsavam, but there is no form for him because of the curse...

Comment: @Keshav - But no other godsess should be worshipped without their respective consorts...Worshipping great goddesses like Lakshmi and parvati with other deities like ganesh, Kubera and other deities will tantamount to committing incest or sin. They should always be worshipped with their respective consorts only.

Answer (score 1):

Lakshmi means "Bliss" and it shows by symbol of "Lotus". Which is the centre of our mind/brain. So if we want "Blissful" we have to awake and open the "Lotus" by Dhayn and Karma.

Saraswati represent Right part of mind/brain by this portion all "Abstract Arts" work. We call it "Gyan" or "Knowing".
Ganesh represent Left part of mind/brain by this portion all "Practical Arts" work. We call it "Vigyan" or "doing.
So when proper Knowing and proper doing works together called "Yog" and it creates the "Bliss".  That we must need to worship Saraswati and Ganesha together for actual worship of Goddess Lakshmi.

Comment: You should cite some sources.