# Why do we worship Goddess Lakshmi and Lord Ganesh on Diwali?

Tags: ganesha, festivals, lakshmi

Diwali the festival of lights is mainly celebrated as on this day Lord Rama came back to Ayodhya after completing their 14 year exile. But generally everywhere we find that we worship Lord Ganesha and Lakshmi mata on Diwali.

- Why is this so?
- Is there any story behind their worship on this day?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/786/36

Comment: Its a bit like that, but not exactly. Also, the answer isn't satisfactory there as it was said that since Lord Ganesha is worshiped before any good thing and Goddess Lakshmi is the goddess of wealth. If that is the reason for worshiping them on Diwali then they should be worshiped on every festival or rather everyday. We do this specially on Diwali so there should be some story or folklore behind it.

Comment: In Bengal, Alakshmi is worshipped and then drived away and then Lakshmi is worshipped and ther are mantras and references for this.But Ganesha is not worshipped on Dipavali as per the tradition.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is said that Lord Vishnu sleeps for 4 months from 11th lunar Ashadh to 11th lunar Kartik. Being bored Goddess Laxmi decides to walk on the earth As Laxmi doesn't have wisdom to shower wealth on right persons so Lord Ganesha accompanies her to guide her. Being the darkest night everyone lights diyas to attract Laxmi to their house and thus worshipping Goddess Laxmi and Ganesh started on Diwali.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! You should cite sources for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is said that once upon a time Lakshmi argued to Lord Vishnu to see the prithvi lok or earth. Lord Vishnu accepted her request, but she did not know anything about the earth. Therefore Lord Vishnu suggested her to go with Lord Ganesha because he is the most intelligent god in the whole universe. Therefore Lord Ganesha and Goddess Lakshmi came to visit on prithvi lok or earth on amavasya so for welcoming the goddess of wealth and the god of intelligency we worship Lord Ganesha and Goddess Lakshmi on the day of diwali. By the diyas, we welcome Lord Rama in Ayodhya.

Answer (score 0):

1. The scientific reason for lighting on Diwali is, this is  **Darkest Night (Dark Moon Night)** in the year that's  why we lightning everywhere.
2. Lord Ganesha got worship by his father that **before worship to any god or goddess lord ganesha should pray first so we pray Lord Ganesha** before start anything (Even Praying to other Lords).
3. **Diwali is festival of  wealth and lord Laxmi is goddess of wealth** so on this festival we worship lord Laxmi.
4. **Lord Ram Come back from Lanka (Shri Lanka) with lots of wealth (Gold)** from Lanka (Initially Sri Lanka was named as sone-ki-lanka means golden Lanka) so that is belongs to wealth so we worship to Lord Laxmi.
5. Why not Lord Ram worship on that day ? so on the same day Lord Ram took a "Agni Pariksha" to his wife Goddess Sita and which is not acceptable by human mankind.

Comment: According to what I have heard & read, Diwali is a festival that symbolises victory of good over evil. But you say that it is a festival of wealth. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Your quit correct but that is a day when Lord Ram Kill Ravan and make his brother new king of Lanka so that lankan people are free from evil that means victory of good over evil. That festival is celebrate as Vijayadashami which also known as Dashahara 10th day after Nauratri festival you get more info on [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vijayadashami)